# O "s" em algumas palavras do português antigo

Tags: português-brasileiro, etimologia, ortografia, português-europeu, diferenças

Olá. Lendo alguns periódicos antigos da Biblioteca Nacional, percebi uma letra que não conhecia, que não é nosso "s" atual, mas que aparecia em algumas palavras, como por exemplo o pronome "se" ou as palavras "distancia" e "freguesia". Parecia um "f" mas sem esse tracinho do meio. Em outras palavras, no entanto, aparecia como "s" mesmo, como por exemplo em "duas", "Silva". Que letra era essa?[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso é um "s longo", que [a Wikipédia explica](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/S_longo) muito bem:

> O s longo (ſ) é uma forma do "s" minúsculo, originalmente utilizado onde o "s" ocorria no meio ou no começo de uma palavra.

Comment: Existe alguma língua que ainda utilize essa letra? Ou era exclusividade do português/línguas latinas?

Comment: @RafaelKing Não era exclusividade. A fonte da resposta (artigo da Wikipedia) menciona o inglês, alemão e italiano; sua versão em inglês também menciona outras línguas latinas e germânicas e referencia [essa postagem](https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Blog/2006/06/rules-for-long-s.html), que menciona outras línguas.

Comment: @RafaelKing era comum na idade média por toda a Europa, é uma herança romana. Hoje em dia a ligadura (uma fuasão) do ſ com o s ainda existe no alemão com a letra ß (ſs)